# rails devise login not working on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, devise, production-environment

I have set up my ROR app environment on production by this link :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

Now it everthing works fine as long as I am using :

```
RackEnv development
```

(search in the link) i.e in development mode.

But as soon as I change it to production

```
RackEnv production
```

I am not able to login into my application.
Seems like 'devise' issue.

Comment: How are you creating your user? seeds.rb? A migration? It's probably not instantiated in your production DB.

Comment: @tirdadc- yes, I am creating them through seeds.rb. If it is creating the problem can you suggest any solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you run:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed`

so that your user is present on production as well. Seeds are only meant for that [initialization](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data), so after this point you'll need to add data through migrations.

Comment: I have created septate DB for production and follow your command, but still not able to login with my LDAP user credentials, although when I override 'valid_ldap_authentication?' function of 'devise' in my users.rb file to provide common password for all users then i can login with the common password.

Comment: It seems like devise have some problem as I mentioned earlier